# NetSuite Suitescript and Third Party API for web services

Tags: web-services, netsuite

I just want to make sure I am on right path, so need your guidance.

I am working on a project where I need to integrate NetSuite with a third party application. The third party application exposes their API's in the form of -

`http:// www........asmx url`

So I have build code as a 'User Event' script in NetSuite to invoke this API; issue the SOAP request; use `nlapiRequestURL()` to get that request in XML; format the data; and then use code such as:

```
customerRecord.setFieldValue('comments', response.getBody());
```

to add the value in NS database? Is this the correct way?

I have a scenario where I need to search for all the new Sales Orders, Customers, etc. created in the third party application to be integrated into NetSuite within 5-10 min. How can I achieve this? There is no trigger in the third party application but only those APIs.

Do I need to write a scheduled script to replicate what I am doing in user event script?

Can someone please suggest the correct method?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Of course things will be much easier if you opt a schedule script in your scenario. User Events are much like action based and doesn't fit the criteria where you have to check every 10 / 15 minutes to find out the updated records.

### Some Important Points:

While using `nlapiRequestURL()` be aware that there are two `versions` of this API :

- A client-side version and a server-side version.
- When you execute this API in a server call, there is no callback parameter. Therefore, the function signature in a server-side call is nlapiRequestURL(url, postdata, headers, httpMethod).
- When you execute this API in a client script, the function signature is nlapiRequestURL(url, postdata, headers, callback, httpMethod).

Again it matters how you're syncing your NS with another third party App. From your view point I can see you want to replicate all the changes from external server to NS. But be sure that you filter the transitional data well to get only the created / updated record. Otherwise you'll be end up with calling 10,000 records unnecessarily every 15 min. and it'll put a load on the NS.

However coming to your later query, NS does provide the flexibility to use Java, .Net,PHP and of course Suitescript. So you can use the either one that suits your requirement. If your incoming data is SOAP based then definately you need an XML parser to parse it. So you can use Java or .Net any of your choice. Otherwise if its in JSON and you want a light weight medium, then you can opt suitescript and it'll ease your doing.

Answer (score 0):

You should always do such things within the NetSuite Scheduled Scripts. NetSuite User Event should not be used as they always require a user action (Record Load, Record Submit) to happen on a NetSuite Record Type for their invocation.

For your use case "search for all the new Sales Order, Customer etc created in third party application to be integrated into NetSuite within 5-10 min", its a good candidate for a scheduled job that searches for all the new data on an external system and then puts it back in NetSuite. Also, since Scheduled Scripts have higher (10000) API Usage Points Limits, you could process a lot many records in a Scheduled Script.

Comment: Thanks Rohit for the answer. Another quick question. Do you think Suitscript is the way to go or is there another option I can go for which will be better in terms of performance.

Can I use dotnet/java code and load in a free web server? Will that work? All Netsuite document talk about dot net/java/php in suitetalk but not sure how to run it from within netsuite.

Comment: SuiteScript is the best solution imo since scripts would run on NetSuite own WebServer (No Cron Job Scheduling/additional Server Maintenance for you). Your use case involves submitting a lot of Customer and Sales Order Records in NetSuite Database and Record Submit via Native SuiteScript is much less expensive an operation than a WebService call.

Comment: @meg Can you also upvote/mark my answer as Accepted in case this answers your original question.! Thanks